# Rendering a collection of partials when the given collection is nil

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Given the following example from the Rails documentation:

```
<%= render(partial: "ad", collection: @advertisements) || "There's no ad to be displayed" %>
```

My question is how to wrap the

> "There's no ad to be displayed"

string into html tag in order to add css classes to it.

For example,

```
<span class='text-muted'>There's no ad to be displayed</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work in your case. 
Here's also some reference that will explain it in more detail: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

```
<%= render(partial: "ad", collection: @advertisements) || content_tag(:span, "There's no ad to be displayed") %>
```